# How to dynamically change radio box values in JSON object using angular 5

Tags: javascript, json, angular5

How to dynamically change radio box values in JSON object using angular 5

**sample.ts :**

```
var sample = [
{
"radioObj":[
{"radio1": "radio1Value","value":0},
{"radio2": "radio2Value","value":0},
{"radio3": "radio3Value","value":0}
]  
},
{
"radioObj":[
{"radio1": "radio1Value","value":0},
{"radio2": "radio2Value","value":0},
{"radio3": "radio3Value","value":0}
] 
},
{
"radioObj":[
{"radio1": "radio1Value","value":0},
{"radio2": "radio2Value","value":0},
{"radio3": "radio3Value","value":0}
] 
}
]
```

**sample.html**

```
<div class="card-body" *ngFor="let row1 of sample; i1 = index" >
    <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let row of row1.radioObj;let i=index" >
        <input type="radio" name="radioname[{{i1}}]"  #default [value]="row.value" 
        [(ngModel)]="row.value" >
    </div>
</div
```

**Expected OUTPUT:**

```
var sample = [
{
"radioObj":[
{"radio1": "radio1Value","value":1},
{"radio2": "radio2Value","value":0},
{"radio3": "radio3Value","value":0}
]  
},
{
"radioObj":[
{"radio1": "radio1Value","value":0},
{"radio2": "radio2Value","value":1},
{"radio3": "radio3Value","value":0}
] 
},
{
"radioObj":[
{"radio1": "radio1Value","value":0},
{"radio2": "radio2Value","value":0},
{"radio3": "radio3Value","value":1}
] 
}
]
```

**Note:**

In the above code **sample** variable having nested array of objects as **"radioObj"** and it will be iterated in the HTML and printed as three sets of radio buttons in three times.

**Step 1:**

If we checked any one of the **radioObj.radio1** then it should be unique should not affect/checked other radio buttons in the **radioObj** object.

**Key :**
If we checked the **radioObj.radio1** then its value should be **1** and other radio buttons value should be **0**